# не работает синтезатор речи silero для python

Tags: python, аудио, pytorch, text-to-speech

У меня возникла проблема с библиотекой silero.
Мой код должен просто озвучивать фразу "Приветствую дорогой друг", но вместо этого появляется вывод каких то символов (Скриншот ниже). Больше ничего не происходит, само окно вывода не закроется пока его не остановишь. При этом в колонках тишина, звук не воспроизводится. Версия python 3.9.0
Помогите пожалуйста

```
import sounddevice as sd
import time
import torch

language = 'ru'
model_id = 'ru_v3'
sample_rate = 48000
speaker = 'baya_v2'
put_accent = True
put_yoo = True
device = torch.device('cpu')
text = "Приветствую дорогой друг"

model, _= torch.hub.load(repo_or_dir='snakers4/silero-models',
                                       model='silero_tts',
                                       language=language,
                                       speaker=model_id)
model.to(device)

audio = model.apply_tts(text=text,
                        speaker=speaker,
                        sample_rate=sample_rate,
                        put_accent=put_accent,
                        put_yoo=put_yoo)

print(text)

sd.play(audio, sample_rate)
time.sleep( len(audio) / sample_rate )
sd.stop()
```

[image: сам код и его вывод]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я убрал:

```
put_yoo=put_yoo
```

и всё заработало.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).